# Missing /etc/netplan/50-cloud-init.yaml

Tags: server, netplan, static-ip

I want a static IP in Ubuntu 20.04 Server. When directed to `/etc/netplan/50-cloud-init.yaml`, I notice I have no such file. I have `/etc/netplan/00-default-nm-renderer.yaml` and `/etc/netplan/00-installer-config.yaml`.

Why would this be? This is a new installation from last week. I am a noob.

Comment: Please [edit your question](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1300990/edit) to show us the entire contents of the two files that you do have. FYI: `50-cloud-init.yaml` is not a required file -- it's optional.

Answer (score 1):

The `/etc/netplan/50-cloud-init.yaml` file only exists on systems configured by cloud-init - which is generally cloud images, not bare-metal servers installed via install media.

You can edit the contents of `/etc/netplan/00-installer-config.yaml` to change your network configuration.